# How to get data from two post methods?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to get data from a form and a javascript function. I am able to get the data from the Form object but I can't seem to get the data from the javascript function. Is there any way I can get data from the javascript function as well?

This is my code

views.py

```py
@app.route('/')
def data():
    form = Form()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form_data = form.info.data
        print(form_data)
        javascript_data = request.form['value'] # this doesn't work
        print(javascript_data)
```

forms.py

```py
class Form:
    info = StringField(
        'Info',
        validators=[
            DataRequired()
        ]
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Javascript that runs when form is submitted

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    $("form").on('submit', function(event)
    {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url : '/',
           data: {
               value : "someValue"
           }
       });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try request.POST.get method

```
...
javascript_data = request.POST.get('value', None)
...
```

Comment: I got an error saying that the request object doesn't have "POST"